# using date to calculate how many days since first date in R?

Tags: r, datetime

I have several dates of measurement for the same specimen. I'm trying to figure out the first day I have and the 2nd, 3rd, 4th...up to 6th day.

here is the [data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/i9613zgrzsodocl/master.csv)

First I took `data$start` and split it

```
#split timestamp into separate date and time vars
temp<-strsplit(as.character(data$start), " ")
mat<-matrix(unlist(temp), ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)
df<-as.data.frame(mat)
colnames(df)<-c("date", "time")
data<-cbind(df, data)
```

then

```
data$date<-as.Date(data$date, "%Y-%m-%d")
data$dob <- ave(as.numeric(data$date), data$mcode, FUN = min)
data$dob <- data$dob - 1
data$pnday <- as.numeric(data$date) - data$dob
```

Both pnd and dob columns have an NA -- sorry if this is silly, any ideas?

I'm new to working with dates/times in R

Comment: It's hard to answer your question unless you give us `data`, so that we both follow what you're talking about when you mention `mcode`, `pnd` and `dob` columns are, or we telepathically connect to you or your R-session... :)

Comment: i've edited with a link to my data...

Answer (score 0):

If you format your data as an [xts](http://cran.r-project.org/package=xts), it will automatically be ordered by date from first to last. To do this, you'll need to make your timestamp readings into POSIXct instances and pass them to the order.by parameter of its constructor. I hope this helps you. If you need further help, please leave a comment, and I'll dig into your data.

Comment: i thought that's what i was doing by saying 'as.date(x, format=)'

Comment: it seems the problem is the way the 'start' variable is being read in. in previous versions of the csv the variable read in as text and so the above R code worked. Now I have no idea....which is why the string split is not working. would appreciate any advice on how to modify it.